# while displaying it is ignoring first row of table

Tags: php, cakephp-bootstrap-ui

It is ignoring first row of table. What am I doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM combo1 group by id ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<center>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['column'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` Why? That's reading the first row, and then completely ignoring it

Comment: yaa storing into DB but not displaying while fetching

Comment: please help me what to do for displaying the first row of the table ...

Comment: what are u trying to achieve here `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<center>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){`

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "<center>" HERE displaying labels for each column and while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

Comment: sorry next is for displaying  inserted data

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

use only one

edit:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM combo1 group by id ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['column'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";        
    }
}
```